# Set fixed size to Image

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui, xcode11

How can I set a fixed size for an Image in SwiftUI? Currently my Image is really big

At the moment I have this structure:

```
struct TweetCell: View {
     var profileImage: Image
     var body: some View {
         HStack {
              profileImage
             VStack {
            ...
         }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way of doing it is via

```swift
profileImage.resizable().frame(width: 50, height: 50)
```

Comment: What's the difference if I don't call resizable() ?

Comment: try it out! instead of resizing the image it crops a 50x50 rectangle out of it

Comment: You can also add a `.scaledToFit()` or `.scaledToFill()` depending on how you want images with different aspect ratios than the frame to fill the view. Fit preserves the aspect ratio, fill distorts the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
There are multiple ways to set fixed size to Image

1) Image("yourImage").frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)

2) Image("yourImage").resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
3) Image("yourImage").frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center).clipped()

Attached the screenshots for all.
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]